# gImageReader Clipboard doesn't work on Windows

Tags: clipboard, ocr, gtk, tesseract-ocr

I'm using gImageReader to do some OCR on Windows 7, and though I can copy from within the application itself, I can't copy to the external Windows 7 clipboard.  I believe the program is gtk based, and that maybe a setting within gtk needs to be changed to enable this functionality; I seem to remember having this issue before, with another gtk for Windows application , but I don't remember what I did to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a gtk related problem. Updating gtk to current version should help, but I haven't tried that yet.